# delayed state update in useEffect with api call

Tags: reactjs, setstate, use-effect

I'm having a problem where spamming 2 buttons aren't updating state correctly.

```
export default function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
    const [showCustom, setShowCustom] = useState(false);
    const customItems = useSelector(flipBoardItems);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (!showCustom) {
                const data = await getFlipBoardContent();
                setItems(() => data);
            } else {
                setItems(() => Object.values(customItems));
            }
        })();
    }, [customItems, showCustom]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Paper>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Button onClick={() => setShowCustom(true)}>Show Custom</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => setShowCustom(false)}>Show Live</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </Paper>
                </div>
         );
```

Problem is, that if I switch showCustom from true to false, it will start an api call, but if I switch it quickly back to true it will complete the api and set items to live, because, at that moment, custom was false, even tho my showCustom is true later.

I have seen multiple examples on how to do it when component unmounts, but haven't been able to find anything related to my problem.

My question is, how can I prevent useEffect api call from updating items state when showCustom is true?

Comment: Are you asking how to abort API calls? You have custom hooks for that

Comment: Your comment would be more helpful if you include an example of one of the custom hooks you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this similar to cancelling when a component unmounts:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let fetchCanceled = false;

        (async () => {
            if (!showCustom) {
                const data = await getFlipBoardContent();

                if (fetchCanceled) {
                  return;
                }

                setItems(data);
            } else {
                setItems(Object.values(customItems));
            }
        })();

        return () => {
          fetchCanceled = true;
        };
    }, [customItems, showCustom]);
```

The return function from `useEffect` is called whenever the value of `showCustom` changes, so if you click `showCustom` after starting to fetch data it will flip `fetchCanceled` to true before setting data.

Also: You don't need the functional form of `setItems` unless you're using the current value of `items` to update that value.